# ReactJS redirect if session

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use `onEnter` with my reactjs app. I want to check if the session is true then make sure the user gets redirected to the dashboard page.

I am wondering if anyone knows why this would not be working?

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
    //import Header from './core/header';

    //PAGES
    import Homes from './core/pages/home';
    import Dashboard from './core/pages/dashboard';
    import Addnew from './core/pages/addnew';

    import './App.css';
    import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

    export function onEnter(nextState, transition, callback) {
      console.log("test")
      const { pathname } = nextState.location
      const isLoggedIn = sessionStorage.getItem('loggedin') === true
      if (pathname === '/' && isLoggedIn) {
        transition('/dashboard') //redirect to Home component
      }
      return callback() // go as it is.
    }

    function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Router>
            <Fragment>
              <Route path="/" exact component={Homes} onEnter={onEnter} />
              <Route path="/dashboard" exact component={Dashboard} />
              <Route path="/dashboard/radio/:stationid" exact component={Dashboard} />
              <Route path="/addnew" exact component={Addnew} />
            </Fragment>
          </Router>
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to also import `Redirect` from `react-router-dom`

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
```

Not exactly sure about your logic but you need to call Redirect like the following;

```
<Redirect
    to={{
      pathname: "/dashboard",
        state: { from: location }
       }}
 />
```

refer to the `react-router` doc https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

Answer (score 0):

From react-router-v4 `onEnter`, `onUpdate`, and `onLeave` is removed,

Docs :https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/migrating.md#on-properties

Try something like

```
<Route exact path="/home" render={() => (
  isLoggedIn() ? (
    <Redirect to="/first"/>
  ) : (
    <Home />
  )
)}/>
```